# Execute command on current tmux session when attached to a window group

Tags: tmux

I usually use two tmux sessions that share a single window group.
My problem is that panes remember the session they were created from, and a tmux command executed in a shell always acts on the parent session of the pane.

```
$ tmux new-session -s s1           # the pane is created here
$ tmux new-session -s s2 -t s1

$ tmux display-message -p '#S'     # executed in s2 but prints out s1
$ tmux set status off              # executed in s2 but hides the status bar in s1
```

A command run in a pane created in `s2` would always act on `s2`.
Direct commands (i.e. `:set status off`) work as expected.

Is there any simple way (without somehow reassigning the pane) to make a command operate on the current session?